# Add to checkout total lines an additional line below shipping in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I need add "Include pack" line with conditional logic to WooCommerce checkout review order section. How it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Fee API that will create in totals line below shipping optionsCode goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works., based on the shipping total x 1.5 (+50%), where you can include your conditional logic, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_pack_fee', 10 , 1 );
function custom_pack_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! is_chekout() )
        return;

    // Add your conditional logic and calculations below

    $percentage     = 1.5; // Percentage (150%)
    $shipping_total = $cart->get_shipping_total();

    if ( $shipping_total > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( __('Include pack', 'woocommerce'), ($shipping_total * $percentage), true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: How to add the HTML/text i.e. `(shipping price + 50% = )` in the table row, like the OP requested as per his screenshot?

Comment: @Devner I don't know, I just have suggested to use the fee api that gives something like you can see in the screenshot on my answer...

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your response. Appreciate it!